# What will happen if I completely remove JS from my Bootstrap template?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap template, mostly for the grid and I want to know what will happen if I remove JS completely from my project?

Note: My project it's a one page portofolio for photographers, has some text , a simple navigation (not from bootstrap ) and the grid + some variables.

Comment: just try it, then you'll see

Comment: Can't tell the difference.....

Comment: If there is no visible difference on any page and no errors in the console then the quick answer is nothing happens. You should test every user inputs, however, in case there are some handlers relying on JS.

Comment: I just want to make the web site as light as possible, that's why I'm asking, I will run some more tests but the page is basically made of the bootstrap responsive grid, links, text, images and none have js handlers..

Comment: Do your drop-down menus work?

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap's menu, I'm using a custom one made for this that don't need any JS it's purely CSS, so the Bootstrap JS it's only for menu's, some buttons, inputs and other actions, but will not affect my website If i delete completely?

Comment: If the goal is to use a lightweight CSS framework you could always try [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) it does not require js.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about `boostrap 3` is that is very easy to customize on their website. All you need to do is select only the things you need, and scroll to the bottom to get a zipped folder containing the compiled CSS.

If you only want the `grid`, [this](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=b1cc000d0ee9fe4beb0bc8821460c111) is the configuration you need. Just scroll to the bottom and download it.